# XCTest won't link classes from my target application

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I added a unit test target in Xcode 6.1 to an existing project.  If I do a simple test like

`XCTestAssert(1 + 1 == 2, @"Addition");`

it builds and works fine.  When I try to use any classes from my target application I get a linker error.  I can't figure out how to get it to link correctly.  Both of the targets are building for the same architectures.  I tried setting up a new project and I can use classes from the target application.  I am probably missing some simple thing, but I can't figure out what it is and I haven't been able to find anything that helps when searching for other solutions.

The error I am getting is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NoteManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ESV_Tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`NoteManager` is the class I am trying to test.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You should check stripping and hidding symbols settings in main target. Linker read your classes from application binary (Application.app/Application) in -bundle_loader option. You can check symbols by this command:

```
nm <path to Application.app/Application> | grep NoteManager
```

I also recommend you to rebuild project after settings changes

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution.  In my target application (not the test target) I needed to set the "Symbols Hidden by Default" flag to NO.